# Overriding Required attribute in view model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a view model that I'm using for an object represented by my website. Let's call it `Student`.

I was happy to minimize my application clutter by using the same view model for my Add, Details, and Edit views.

However, some elements should not be editable in the Edit view, things like Password. So I removed these from the view.

However, now `ModelState.IsValid` reports false on the postback.

Is there a straight forward way to use the same view for all of these views but somehow override the required status for my edit view?

*Note: I realize I could use hidden fields. But I'm not comfortable sending data such as a password to the client and back. I'd just prefer to not expose it here at all.*

Comment: Have you considered creating  **view specific** view models ? Use inheritance as needed.

Comment: attributes are compile time metadata they are not flexible for what you are requesting. Adding to one of the already provided suggestions, make a common base view model and have the properties virtual. in the view specific view models, override the necessary properties and apply the required attribute as needed.

Comment: @Shyju: Yes, I did think about that, and I may take that approach if there's no simpler ones. But I was just happy about minimizing the number of models needed.

Comment: Minimizing the models doesn't make things simpler if you are left with bloated and complicated models. In this case, splitting into different models is the simpler option.

Comment: @JMadel: How does minimizing the models equate to bloated and complicated models? I would say the two are complete opposites.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: Using fewer models but still the same amount of code means more code is contained within each model. I meant that it is better to split the models up rather than filling one model with several models' worth of code.

Comment: @JMadel: I really don't follow you. What's all this code you're talking about? It's a viewmodel--a collection of properties. I need code for each action anyway (add, view, create, etc.). I don't see where anything is becoming more bloated or complicated.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: Maybe it is I who does not follow you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as others have pointed out, this situation usually calls for different view model classes. And that this can be accomplished more concisely using inheritance.

But there is another option. Something that, while not perfect, is a little closer to what I was looking for.

When your form posts back, any errors are stored in `ModelState`. If you know there are some errors that don't matter, you can clear these. Note that clearing all the errors will cause `ModelState.IsValid` to change from `false` to `true`.

```
public ActionResult Edit(TrainerModel model)
{
    ModelState[nameof(model.Email)]?.Errors?.Clear();
    ModelState[nameof(model.Password)]?.Errors?.Clear();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //
    }
    return View(model);
 }
```

Comment: But would that bypass client side validation?

Comment: @Nkosi: I had removed these input fields from my view, so that isn't an issue for me. If your view still had these fields, then obviously client-side validation would still complain.

Comment: This was the exact solution I needed. I was re-using a model for creation and for update, where an empty value for certain field would mean "preserve current value" during edit, but was mandatory during create. This allowed me to avoid creating a model with all the same fields but with just one of them not being [Required],